# nested utree with boost::spirit::qi?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost, boost-spirit-qi

I try to parse some hierarchical data into boost::utree structure, yet it doesnt seem to work as expexted.
This is what i do:

```
qi::rule<const char*, utree(), chars::space_type> inner, outer;
outer %= '<' > qi::int_ > *inner > '>';
inner %= outer | qi::as_string[qi::lexeme[+(chars::alnum - '>')]];
const char txt[] = "<21 hello <34 some> strange <12 world>>";
const char* txtIt = txt;
try {
    if (qi::phrase_parse(txtIt, txt + strlen(txt), outer, chars::space, data))
    {
        std::cout << "Numbers parsed" << std::endl;
        HGrammar::traverseData()(data);
    }

    //return;
    data.clear();
 }catch(qi::expectation_failure<...>(...)) ...
```

where traverseData() is just a call to operator<<(cout, utree).
This is what i get:

> ( 21 "hello" 34 "some" "strange" 12 "world" )

Yet i want the utree to reflect the nested nature of the string feeded into phrase_parse(). Like:

> ( 21 "hello" ( 34 "some" ) "strange" ( 12 "world" ) )

How do I get this sort of output?

PS Used boost 1.49.0 with Visual Studio 2010

Answer (score 3):

It was rather simple...
I just had to change the declaration of the 'outer' qi rule to:

```
qi::rule<const char*, utree::list_type(), chars::space_type> outer;
```

thus changing the rule's attribute type to utree::list_type. Yet I have no idea why this works...

And in boost 1.47.0 there is another bug with utree failing to propagate its attribute value when used in conjunction with semantic actions.